# H2 headers missing in Product Description RWD base theme

Tags: css, rwd-theme, product-view

I have noticed that all of the h2 headers within my product descriptions are not shown.

If I view the source within a browser all of the information is there, its just not visible.

h1,h3,h4,h5,h6 all work perfectly

I have now tested this on 3 different customer installs of Magento 1.9.

The h2 headers work perfectly within the category description.

Has anyone else seen this?

---

we added the following so it is easy to see.

## H1

### H2

#### H3

H4

H5

H6

http://www.seadog.com.au/propulse-adjustable-pitch-propeller-6902-10-4-13-splines.html
http://www.deckside.com.au/test-product-111.html

Comment: It is work perfectly my end.
Can you please send you product url?

Comment: Are you using nay adblock or something ? try disabling it and view again

Comment: I'm not using any adblock .

Comment: The first 2 sites are mine. The bottom one is a friends and he has the same problem.

Comment: http://www.seadog.com.au/propulse-adjustable-pitch-propeller-6902-10-4-13-splines.html
http://www.deckside.com.au/test-product-111.html
http://hunterbowls.staging.webqem.net/997-australian-made-pedal-pushers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS is merged (which is good) so I can't for sure point to the exact file.  However, in your CSS you have the following:

```
.collateral-tabs dd h2 {
    display: none;
}
```

It is hiding the h2 tags in your tabs.

Guessing based on your theme, look at this file:

/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css

line 5353

If you want to keep "details" hidden, change the above to:

```
.collateral-tabs dd .tab-content > h2 {
       display: none;
}
```

Comment: Your correct. Thank you. it looks like this has been added to remove the word "Details"

Comment: I edited my answer to add how you can hide "details" and keep the other h2s.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion above was correct.

I have changed 
 .collateral-tabs dd h2 {
  display: none;
 }
to

.collateral-tabs dd h2 {
  display: block;
 }

After this change was made the words "DETAILS" has now appeared at the top of the Product description page. This is OK by me.

http://www.deckside.com.au/test-product-111.html

Comment: Yes, please accept the answer if it worked out your issue!